# Why do i get Runtime Error on the Codeforces platform on these 2 codes?

Tags: python, python-3.7

here is my submission link :
-for the following problem : https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1257/C https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/1257/65506141

```
test=int(input())
for testing in range(test):
    n=int(input())
    t=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    if n<=1:
        print(-1)
    else :
        l=[x for x in t if t.count(x)>1]
        l=[x for x in set(l)]
        pointer=[]
        for x in l:
            joker=True
            i=0
            while i<len(t):
                if t[i]==x and joker:
                    s=i
                    joker=False
                if t[i]==x and not joker and i!=s:
                    pointer.append(t[s:i+1])
                    joker=True
                    i-=1
                i+=1
        print(min(map(len,pointer)))
```

thanks in advance ^^, i still don't get from what runtime errors come from

Comment: Did you try running the code locally to get a traceback?

Comment: yes i did it worked fine :/

Answer (score -1):

i found out the main cause of it it is mainly cause try or expect u need to avoid excpetion like list getting empty and calling it after that for something else . i just fixed the code :

```
test=int(input())
for testing in range(test):
    n=int(input())
    t=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    if n<=1 :
        print(-1)
        continue
    else :
        pointer=[[False,0] for i in range(max(max(t),len(t))+1)]
        first=True
        mini=-1
        for i in range(len(t)):
            if not pointer[t[i]][0]:
                pointer[t[i]][1]=i
                pointer[t[i]][0]=True
                continue
            if pointer[t[i]][0]:
                if first :
                    mini=i-pointer[t[i]][1]+1
                    first=False
                else:
                    a=i-pointer[t[i]][1]+1
                    if mini>a:
                        mini=a
            pointer[t[i]][1]=i
            pointer[t[i]][0]=True
            if mini==2:
                break
    print(mini)
```